# Ho to incorporate React or Nextjs into an existing template project?

Tags: reactjs

So at my current job, we have an admin dashboard that was built using a template from https://startbootstrap.com/theme/sb-admin-2

Currently we have a ton of jQuery that is being used.

I have been trying to figure this out but have not had any luck.

I have tried adding

```
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';

function NavigationBar() {
  // TODO: Actually implement a navigation bar
  return <h1>Hello from React!</h1>;
}

const domNode = document.getElementById('navigation');
const root = createRoot(domNode);
root.render(<NavigationBar />);
```

from the docs and nothing.

Not sure what I need to do.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.